# NOPASSWD option not working in sudo

Tags: sudo

I am trying to add `NOPASSWD` option for existing user who belongs to the `sudo` group and have admin rights. I added this line in `sudoers` file:

```
max     ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But it still ask me for password when i try to execute command with `sudo`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `sudoers` file is parsed line by line and the last rule prevails for a given user.

So, you need to add this rule after all other rules applicable for the given user to have this in effect.

For example, if the user `max` belongs to `sudo` group, then the following won't have desired result:

```
max     ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Reverse the order to get `max` passwordless `sudo` access:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
max     ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Or better yet, a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` (which are parsed at the end of the main file in default configuration)

Comment: Note to future readers: there are restrictions on what you can and cannot name files in the `/etc/sudoers.d/` folder.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/71851251/8859073